# What's the difference between CSS3's :root pseudo class and html?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I can't seem to find much information about this.

[Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/30/how-to-use-css3-pseudo-classes/) seems to be saying that `html` and `:root` are the same thing but surely there must be a tiny difference?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

From the [W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:root):

> The `:root` pseudo-class represents an element that is the root of the document. In HTML, this is always the HTML element.

CSS is a general purpose styling language. It can be used with other document types, not only with HTML, it can be used with SVG for example.

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/) (emphasis mine):

> This specification defines Cascading Style Sheets, level 2 revision 1 (CSS 2.1). CSS 2.1 is a style sheet language that allows authors and users to attach style (e.g., fonts and spacing) to **structured documents (e.g., HTML documents and XML applications)**.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware that you could style SVGs with CSS like that. Accepted answer for citing source. :)

Comment: Not only SVG, but anything that's based on XML. Including XHTML.

Comment: Is it better to use `:where(html)` or `:root` ?

Comment: If you're making default styles and variables, `:where(html)` is better because it has lowest specificity, that way end developers can easily override the styles and variables. `:root` could potentially be better if you need the higher specificity, like if for some reason your overriding style gets loaded before the default style in `:where(html)`.

Answer (score 136):

One technical difference between them is that `:root` - being a pseudo class has a greater specificity than `html` (a type selector)

```css
:root {
  color: red
}
html {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>hello world</div>
```

So, in the above example, the `:root` selector overrides the `html` selector and the text appears red.

Comment: one interesting difference is that other pseudo class (like `:after`) won't be affected by `:root`. On the other hand specifying `html` make sure that everything within the `html` tag is affected even the other pseudo class.

Answer (score 38):

For HTML documents, there is no difference - your root element is the `<html>` tag, so `html{}` and `:root{}` are (besides from a difference in specificity) semantically equivalent.

However, you can apply CSS not only to HTML, but all XML-like documents. That's why `:root` is there - to target the document's root element regardless of document type. Most people are confused by the difference because the overwhelmingly predominant use case for CSS is styling HTML documents.

Example:
You can style SVG documents with CSS. When styling it, your root element will (obviously;-)) not be `html` but `svg`. See the following list of [SVG tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element).

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to consider is that it's *technically* possible to replace the root element using javascript:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id=test>
      This will become the root element!
      <style>
        :root { text-decoration: underline; }
        html { color: red; } /* this selector will stop working */
      </style>
  </div>
  <button onclick=document.documentElement.replaceWith(test)>click to replace the root</button>
</body>
</html>
```