# Is :root really useless?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I know that `:root` can be used to select `html` tag for HTML file and to select `svg` tag for `svg` file (regarding styling XML files this is something really strange and not applicable for me), but I don't see sense to prefer `:root` over `html` or `svg` selectors. Applying the same styles for HTML and SVG seem really odd for me using `:root`. I am sure that this is not realistic scenario.

The only valid application of `:root` I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29727884/1548895) that it can be used to override `html` styles (because pseudoclass selector has more priority than type selector), but I would avoid often overriding of `html` and place specific CSS file links later in order to avoid this need.

So the question: are there any real world application of `:root` where it wouldn't be just an odd alternative to `html` (or `svg` for SVG file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the vast majority of authors working with HTML, there are only two practical differences between `:root` and `html`:

1. `:root`, being a pseudo-class, is more specific. If you require the lesser specificity of a type selector, it's entirely acceptable to use `html` instead of `:root`.
2. `:root` can be used to hide rules from Internet Explorer 8 and older (a use case that perhaps isn't prevalent in 2017 but was fairly common half a decade ago).

Other than that, the `:root` pseudo-class is indeed designed primarily for the use case of matching the root element in an arbitrary document without having to know the type of element, which means XML-based languages and even other, non-XML-based types of documents. Remember that as of level 3, the Selectors module is designed for a variety of uses with a variety of document languages, and not just styling HTML elements with CSS (which is why it's now simply called "Selectors" and not "CSS Selectors", despite it being a CSS module).

Additionally, for host languages where the root element doesn't have its own type (e.g. in a language where `element` may be both the root element, and nested), `:root` is necessary for distinguishing the root element from nested elements (though alternatives exist, like `:not(:nth-child(n))` with equal specificity in Selectors 3, or `:not(* > *)` with *zero* specificity in Selectors 4).

Comment: Regarding case#2 I would use conditional comments to apply specific rules for IE8-. Using IE8- styling as default and overriding it in other browsers seems very wrong approach.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov: Yeah, I do the same, rarely ever making use of selector hacks. Nevertheless, many other authors use them, and this is one example of a hack that is commonly used.